# CalenderView In Android

Tags: android, calendar

I need to develop a `CalenderView` in Android, which should look similar to the following,

Output of `Calendar` which I need

[image: UI Glitch in ListView]

I have Googled for it and followed the steps, but it am not getting the exact output.

I have attached XML and JAVA code [This is the output I am getting now.

[image: UI Glitch in ListView]
Here is the java code

[image: UI Glitch in ListView]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Comment: okay, I will follow it next time, Currently I am learning. So, I have posted basic code.

Comment: i think you have to selct any date and everything goes right.

Comment: I just need to display only one month as I have attached the output image in question

Comment: not "next time". Do it now

Comment: you can use this library https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

Comment: @Gaurav is it not possible in default CalenderView?

Comment: https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

Answer (score 1):

I just found only way to reduce the height of `calendar` thats not a good way to do this, instead of `CalendarView` you can use **[Material Calendar View Library](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview)**. This library has lot more customisation than official one.

**Usage**

1. Add compile `'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.3'` to your dependencies.
2. Add `MaterialCalendarView` into your layouts or view hierarchy.
3. Set a `OnDateSelectedListener` or call `MaterialCalendarView.getSelectedDates()` when you need it.

[Javadoc Available Here](http://prolificinteractive.github.io/material-calendarview/)

**Example:**

```
<com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/calendarView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:mcv_showOtherDates="all"
app:mcv_selectionColor="#00F"
/>
```

for more info and customisation you can follow [CUSTOMIZATION_BUILDER](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/blob/master/docs/CUSTOMIZATION_BUILDER.md)